# How do I check the ulimits of a running docker container?

Tags: docker, containers, limit, devops, ulimit

How do I check the ulimits of a running docker container? There are a lot of articles on setting it, but how do I check it in the first place?

Comment: go in and type ulimit -a?

Answer (score 3):

You can access that kind of information via `docker container inspect`.

Specifically, you'll find it under `HostConfig/Ulimit`. You could grep it or extract it via some json decoding, or use the filter option of `docker container inspect` to access it directly:

`docker container inspect -f "{{.HostConfig.Ulimits}}" <container_name>`

Comment: It outputs `[]` :(

Comment: Then there is no ulimit set?

Comment: Then what ulimit does it use?

Comment: I'd assume none?